# sqlDataSource select not work with where clause

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, sqldatasource

I bind gridview to sqldatasource.my problem is that when i use sqldatasource without where clause in select statement it works fine,but when I use it with where clause its work fine in Query Builder test and return records but not working in runtime.
I used Sql Profiler and see query not run when i use where clause.I heard .NET prevent run query with where clause because of sql injection but I dont know how to correct my query.
My sqldatasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:chargeDBConnectionString %>"  SelectCommand="SELECT CARDNUMBER, VISITDATE, ACCNUMBER, ACTIONCODE FROM LOGTABLE WHERE (CARDNUMBER = @cardno OR @cardno IS NULL AND CARDNUMBER &lt;&gt; N'-' AND @ttype = 1 OR @ttype = 0) AND (VISITDATE &gt;= @fdate AND VISITDATE &lt;= @edate) AND (ACCNUMBER = @accno OR @accno IS NULL AND ACCNUMBER &lt;&gt; N'-' AND @ttype = 0 OR @ttype = 1) AND (ACTIONCODE = @actioncode OR @actioncode IS NULL)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="cardNo" Name="cardno" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlType" Name="ttype" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="fromDate" Name="fdate" />
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="toDate" Name="edate" />
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="accNo" Name="accno" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddltransname" Name="actioncode" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely culprit is that one of your parameters is evaluating to null, and the `SqlDataSource` is cancelling the select query.

To correct that, you need to set the [SqlDataSource.CancelSelectOnNullParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.cancelselectonnullparameter.aspx) property to false (it is true by default) in your SqlDataSource declaration:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:chargeDBConnectionString %>"  
    SelectCommand="SELECT CARDNUMBER, VISITDATE, ACCNUMBER, ACTIONCODE FROM LOGTABLE WHERE (CARDNUMBER = @cardno OR @cardno IS NULL AND CARDNUMBER &lt;&gt; N'-' AND @ttype = 1 OR @ttype = 0) AND (VISITDATE &gt;= @fdate AND VISITDATE &lt;= @edate) AND (ACCNUMBER = @accno OR @accno IS NULL AND ACCNUMBER &lt;&gt; N'-' AND @ttype = 0 OR @ttype = 1) AND (ACTIONCODE = @actioncode OR @actioncode IS NULL)"
    CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="cardNo" Name="cardno" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlType" Name="ttype" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="fromDate" Name="fdate" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="toDate" Name="edate" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="accNo" Name="accno" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddltransname" Name="actioncode" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```